# AutoMapper map a collection Property value from its Parent property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mapping, automapper, asp.net-core-2.0

I have two models, `Receipt.cs` and `ReceiptProduct.cs`. What I want to achieve is to map the ICollection `ReceiptProducts` fields like `PurchaseOrderId` and  `ReceiptId` from its parent `Receipt`.

**Receipt.cs**

```
public class Receipt
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Reference { get; set; }
        public string PurchaseOrderId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ReceiptProduct> ReceiptProducts { get; set; }
    }
```

**ReceiptProduct.cs**

```
public class ReceiptProduct
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string ReceiptId { get; set; }
        public string PurchaseOrderId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string ProductId { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }
    }
```

- ReceiptProducts.ReceiptId <= Receipt.Id
- ReceiptProducts.PurchaseOrderId <= Receipt.PurchaseOrderId

I tried the below code. But I got the error

```
CreateMap<DataEntities.Receipt, BusinessEntities.Receipt>()
 .ForMember(dest => dest.ReceiptProducts.Select(x=>x.ReceiptId), automapper => automapper.MapFrom(src => src.Id));
```

**Error :** `AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException: Custom configuration for members is only supported for top-level individual members on a type.`

So how to map that collection property values.

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
public class ReceiptProduct
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string ReceiptId { get; set; }
    public string PurchaseOrderId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }

    **public Receipt Receipt { get; set; }**

}
```

Mapping

```
CreateMap<DataEntities.ReceiptProduct, BusinessEntities.Receipt>()
.ForMember(dest => x=>x.ReceiptId, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Receipt.Id))
.ForMember(dest => x=>x.PurchaseOrderId , opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Receipt.PurchaseOrderId))
.ForMember(dest => x=>x.Reference , opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Receipt.Reference ));
```

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve the Mapping without touching my Business Entity.

Comment: Don't use mapping then just a new property to your Receipt Entity

 [NotMapped]
 public string ReceiptId { get
{
 return ReceiptProducts!=null? ReceiptProducts.First().ReceiptId: string.Empty();
}
 }

Comment: I am getting this error when i try to use Mapping => Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: .ForMember(dest => x=>x.ReceiptId,opts.MapFrom(src => src.Receipt.Id.ToString())